# What would be the select query to obtain below output (Oracle 11g)?

Tags: sql, oracle

What would be the select query in Oracle 11g?

```
Input Table
------------------
Feed_id    User_Id
CL300      K111222;K555444;M123123

Required Output
--------------------------
Feed_id    User_Id
CL300       K111222
CL300       K555444
CL300       M123123
```

Comment: what database you are using?

Comment: Oracle 11g database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee937/15)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ("Feed_id" varchar2(5), "User_Id" varchar2(23))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t ("Feed_id", "User_Id")
         VALUES ('CL300', 'K111222;K555444;M123123')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
  "Feed_id",
  trim(regexp_substr("User_Id", '[^;]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as User_Id
from 
  t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace("User_Id", '[^;]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee937/15/0)**:

```
| Feed_id | USER_ID |
|---------|---------|
|   CL300 | K111222 |
|   CL300 | K555444 |
|   CL300 | M123123 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH input_table AS 
 (
   SELECT  'CL300'                   AS  feed_id, 
           'K111222;K555444;M123123' AS user_id 
   FROM     dual
 )
 SELECT   feed_id,
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(REPLACE(user_id, ';;', '; ;'),';;','; ;'), '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS user_id
 FROM     input_table
 CONNECT  BY
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(REPLACE(user_id, ';;', '; ;'),';;','; ;'), '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```